# Where to find linux-source 3.12 package for saucy

Tags: 13.10

The mainline kernel on Ubuntu shows

3.12 available in saucy

http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.12-saucy/

But where can i find the linux-source package for the same.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=linux-source

The linux source package above does not shows 3.12 choice for saucy

Thanks

Comment: did you want to update kernal?

Comment: I updated the kernel to 3.12 but i need source also as nvidia drivers need source also to be installed for compilation.

Comment: if apt-get install linux-source doesn't get you the sources for the running kernel, file a bug.  generally, it should be a metapackage that points to the running kernel sources.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below command on terminal to download 3.12 kernal source,

```
apt-get source linux-source-3.12.0
```